# ImageMagick convert adds whitespace when converting PDF to PNG

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick to convert the following PDF to an PNG file.

[Click here to download the PDF from IMSLP](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/2/20/IMSLP83072-SIBLEY1802.13122.39d9-39087009515125score.pdf) ([Permalink](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ReverseLookup/83072) if the direct download is broken)

In a PDF viewer it looks nice:

[image]

but when converting with `convert -density 300 -background white -alpha off -alpha remove file.pdf /tmp/file.png`

the image gets a large white margin:

[image]

I do not want to trim the image afterwards, I just want ImageMagick to somehow respect the view-port or however that viewing information is being encoded in the PDF. Does anyone know which command-line parameter might enable this behavior?

Edit 10.03.2022: I'm using ImageMagick 7.1.0.16 with Ghostscript 9.55.0 inside an Alpine Linux docker image.

Comment: At a guess your PDF file has a CropBox which differs from the MediaBox. In the absence of any directions, Ghostscript will use the MediaBox. If you want it to use the CropBox instead then you need to set -dUseCropBox. I don't know how you would go about doing that from ImageMagick so you may be better off using Ghostscript directly to create a PNG file with something like "gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o out.png -dUseCropBox input.pdf". Of course if you know how to modify the GS command line invocation from IM then that would be simpler.

Comment: And indeed your file has page descriptions like "<</Contents 73 0 R/CropBox[79.3701 323.15 715.276 1209.83]/MediaBox[0 0 840 1224]". If I use -dUseCropBox then I see what you expect, if I don;t then I see extra white space as you show above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint from [KenS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701996/kens) was exactly what I was looking for - the PDF defines a CropBox that ImageMagick 7.1.0 was not using by default. The solution therefore is to modify the command to include the following [`-define`](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=9993) information:

```
convert -define pdf:use-cropbox=true file.pdf /tmp/file.png
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your extra margin in ImageMagick 6.9.12-42 using Ghostscript 9.54.  But changing the density does not seem to have any effect.

```
convert -density 300 -background white file.pdf[1] x2.png
```

[image]

The issues may be a malformed PDF. How was it created? Also what version of Ghostscript are you using?  It could be a GS version issue.

If this was a scanned PDF that is a raster image in a vector PDF shell, then you could just use pdfimages to extract the raster files.  See https://manpages.debian.org/testing/poppler-utils/pdfimages.1.en.html